# Python Class __div__ issue

Tags: python, class, operators, tuples, divide

The tuples represent fractions. I'm trying to divide the fractions by multiplying by the reciprical

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self._x=(1,2)
    def __div__(self,div_fraction):
        return (self._x[0]*div_fraction[1],self._x[1]*div_fraction[0])

y=Test()
z=y/(1,3)
print(z)
```

Gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/test.py", line 8, in <module>
   z=y/(1,3)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Test' and 'tuple'
```

Yet when I change the `__div__` to `__mul__` and use `*` instead of `/` it does what it should.

How do I fix the exception I'm getting?

Comment: `y` is an object of type `Test`, what would you expect to be the result of dividing an object with a tuple ?

Comment: @alfasin: Whatever the method defines it to be.

Comment: yes I realize that but shouldn't it follow my __div__ method where i give it the numbers from the __init__?  It works when i use __mul__.

Answer (score 79):

Python 3.x uses `__truediv__` and `__floordiv__`. `__div__` is 2.x-only.

Answer (score 7):

had the same problem the other day.

see if __future__.division is active in your environment. if so, you need to define __truediv__ as well.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions